# Parse SDK Android, My App Crashes in GenyMotion but in real cellphone works

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

I'm using Parse as my Backend service for my application, and im following the quickstart guide of Parse of Test to see that is correctly installed the Parse SDK, https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing

Gradle it's Ok, Compiling Ok, but when i trying to run my project in the emulator the app crashes. (I'm using **GenyMotion** to emulate), but when i use my cellphone it works.

> GenyMotion Virtual Machine Specs

```
**Nexus 4**
Android 5.0.0 -  Api 21
2 Procesors
2048 MB of RAM
```

My PC has 6 GB of RAM.

> LogCat

```
12-12 22:40:50.745 2150-2150/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-12 22:40:51.059 2150-2150/com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
12-12 22:40:51.060 2150-2150/com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid I/MultiDex: install
12-12 22:40:51.060 2150-2150/com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
12-12 22:40:51.307 2150-2189/com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
12-12 22:40:51.327 2150-2150/com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid D/Atlas: Validating map...
12-12 22:40:51.410 2150-2189/com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
12-12 22:40:51.411 2150-2189/com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
12-12 22:40:51.429 2150-2189/com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
12-12 22:40:51.490 2150-2189/com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-12 22:40:51.563 2150-2189/com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-12 22:40:51.594 2150-2189/com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-12 22:40:51.594 2150-2189/com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xef708ec0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-12 22:40:51.791 2150-2186/com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf6ef046e in tid 2186 (ECUTOR-thread-1)
```

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        try {
            Parse.initialize(this);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject.put("foo", "bar");
        testObject.saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

> App Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true //I enable this for not get an Exception when the app is compiling
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile project(':Parse-1.11.0') //I was imported the Parse library
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.danyj.parsetoandroid">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="APPLICATION_ID" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="CLIENT_KEY" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```